# How to represent a 'char' in rosmsg files

Tags: ros, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have to represent character(unsigned char) in ros msg files. As mentioned in the wiki, they have primitive types for string, integer, floats but not for the character.

However the wiki does say that `char: deprecated alias for uint8` . I do not know what does that mean.

How can I represent something like `unsigned char code[N];` `from C++ where N=2;` into msg format. Would it be `uint8[] code`. Where do I put in the `'2'` or I dont have to put it and msg fomat finds out the length of array itself.

[Here is the link to wiki for ros msg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/msg)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73309/how-to-represent-a-%27char%27-in-rosmsg-files/) by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2013-08-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just use a `uint8` to store a char in your message type.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [micheal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5403/micheal/) on 2013-08-16**:
@felix k how would i represent something like "unsigned char code[N];" from C++ where "N=2;" into msg format. Would it be "uint8[] code". Where do I put in the "2" or I dont have to put it and msg fomat finds out the length of array itself.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-08-16**:
You can put the 2 or not. If you put it, it's fixed length array. If you don't put it, the data will be dynamic length.